# I want to add Android Checkbox(SWITCH) to my data array for TableView Using appcelerator titanium?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

I created table view with rows, those contains label and switch box , style is check box. My requirement is, among those row check boxes, I select some of them. Then after, I want those check boxes which are checked and which are unchecked. Here is my code:

```
// My Array Data for Table-view

var checkboxArray = [  { title: "Mountain View (North America)\nCloudy", leftImage:  "http://www.google.com/ig/images/weather/cloudy.gif" },
{ title: "Sucre (South America)\nMostly Cloudy", leftImage: "http://www.google.com/ig/images/weather/mostly_cloudy.gif" },
{ title: "Prague (Europe)\nClear", leftImage: "http://www.google.com/ig/images/weather/sunny.gif" },
{ title: "St Petersburg (Europe)\nSnow", leftImage: "http://www.google.com/ig/images/weather/snow.gif" },];


// My Android checkbox

var checkbox = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
style:Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
title:"Sound Enabled",
value:true
}); 

// My Header label inside table-view

var headerLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  backgroundColor:'#035385',
  color:"white",
  font:{ fontSize: 30, fontWeight:"bold" },
  text:"Favoriete Merken",
  textAlign:"center",
  height:45,
  width:500
});

// My Table View

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
  backgroundColor:"white",
  data:checkboxArray,
  headerView:headerLabel,
  separatorColor:"black",
  top:0,
  width:'auto'
});

win2.add(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rows created via object literals cannot have views added to them. But if you create the row via Ti.UI.createTableViewRow, you can. So to add checkboxes, just change your example to create the rows explicitly, add the checkboxes, store a reference to the checkboxes, and you're done.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
});

var rows = [];
var data = [
    { title: 'Mountain View (North America)\nCloudy', leftImage: 'http://www.google.com/ig/images/weather/cloudy.gif' },
    { title: 'Sucre (South America)\nMostly Cloudy', leftImage: 'http://www.google.com/ig/images/weather/mostly_cloudy.gif' },
    { title: 'Prague (Europe)\nClear', leftImage: 'http://www.google.com/ig/images/weather/sunny.gif' },
    { title: 'St Petersburg (Europe)\nSnow', leftImage: 'http://www.google.com/ig/images/weather/snow.gif' }
];

for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
    row.add(Ti.UI.createImageView({
        image: data[i].leftImage,
        width: 45, height: 45,
        left: 0
    }));
    row.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: data[i].title, textAlign: 'left',
        color: '#000',
        left: 50, right: 50
    }));
    row.add(data[i].switch = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
        style: Ti.UI.Android && Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
        title: 'Sound Enabled',
        value: true,
        right: 5,
        width: 40
    }));
    rows[i] = row;
}

win.add(Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data: rows,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    separatorColor: 'black',
    headerView: Ti.UI.createLabel({
        backgroundColor: '#035385',
        color: 'white',
        font: { fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold' },
        text: 'Favoriete Merken', textAlign: 'center',
        height: 45
    }),
    bottom: 45
}));

var alertFirstSwitchValue = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Alert First Switch Value',
    bottom: 0, right: 0, left: 0,
    height: 45
});
alertFirstSwitchValue.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert(data[0].switch.value);
});
win.add(alertFirstSwitchValue);

win.open();
```